# I'm bad with plotting, looping, dataframes, in general

Tags: python, string, loops, tuples, subplot

dfset is set of dataframes; I want to plot histograms and a fitted distribution to each, label each, and reproduce in a nice 2x2 subplot.

I cannot figure out how to add title when I'm looping through the subplots. (1) I cannot figure out how to convert the "titles" in dfset (e.g. df15NOL, df16NOL) to strings; and (2) I cannot figure out how to loop through multiple, uh, loops. I don't know the technical term, but the things we're looping through.

For example, in matlab, using integer indexing (I think?), for i in range(5) then you can loop through each item in dfset and dfstr by their position. I'm sure I can do it in python, but I wonder what the most efficient method might be.

Also would appreciate input on de-janking the subplot counter, there must be an easier way I'm sure.

```
dfset = (df15NOL, df16NOL, df15YOL, df16YOL)
dfstr = ?

figure, axes = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(15,15))
ct1 = 2
ct2 = 2

for dfel in dfset:
    mu, std = norm.fit(dfel['Store Sales'])
    axes[a,b].hist(dfel['Store Sales'],bins=20,density=True,alpha=0.6)
    xmin, xmax = plt.xlim()
    x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax,100)
    p = norm.pdf(x,mu,std)
    a = ct1 % 2
    ct1 += 1
    b = floor(ct2 % 2)
    ct2 += 0.5
    axes[a,b].plot(x, p, 'k', linewidth=2)
    title = f'mu = {mu}, std = {std}'
    axes[a,b].set_title(title)
    
plt.show()
```

Comment: please post your data so we can try to recreate the issue.  You can use `df.to_dict()` for each df in df_set

Comment: And make the title relevant to the problem..